# Java inheritance diagram

Tags: java, inheritance

Im student, learning java inheritance.

I made a class diagram and i had a feedback in class that i missuses inheritance.

(Program making is “bitcoin mining”)

I made a ‘Digger’ class which describes about mining machine.

And made a ‘ClockConfigurableDigger’ class which inheritances ‘digger’ class. This class makes mining machine that can overclock or underclock.

And made a
‘DurablityRecoverDigger’ class that inheritances ‘ClockConfigurableDigger’class.
This class can both change clock and recover its durablity.

My mentor says that using inheritance this way is wrong.

And I am thinking the reason(why he said this is wrong ) is that clockConfigurablityDigger is has-a relationship than is-a relationship to Digger. That clockConfigurablity shoudnt be a child class of Digger class. Just because ClockConfigurableDigger has one more function than Digger class.

Do you think my reason is right?

Or do you have another opinion of my class diagram?

Thank you for reading!

Comment: A good rule of thumb is "avoid inheritance". It sounds a lot better in theory than it is in practice. Unfortunately it took some time to realise this, so there's still a lot of this `Digger -> ClockConfigurableDigger -> DurabilityRecoverDigger` kind of inheritance you've built that doesn't result in good design. Always prefer composition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Composition** and **inheritance** are both powerful object oriented programming paradigms in establishing relationships between classes and objects.

**Inheritance is Fundamental**

> Inheritance is fundamental to object-oriented programming. A
>   programming language may have objects and messages, but without
>   inheritance it is not object-oriented (merely “object-based”, but
>   still polymorphic).

**…and so is Composition**

> Composition is also fundamental to every language. Even if the
>   language does not support composition (rare these days!), humans still
>   think in terms of parts and components. It would be impossible to
>   break down complex problems into modular solutions without
>   composition.

(Statements above are [citations from Composition vs. Inheritance: How to Choose?](https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/composition-vs-inheritance-how-choose))

**How do you tell them apart?**

While both serve the same purpose of establishing relationships between classes and objects (i.e. polymorphism, reuse, specialization and extension), they do it in a rather distinct way that sets them apart.

Inheritance is when you design your types around what they are and composition is when you design types around what they do.

This little detail is quite significant in object oriented design. It is the basis for the rule of thumb, and a tenet of good object oriented design, used in determining when to use either paradigms i.e inheritance follows an **IS-A** relationship while composition follows a **HAS-A** relationship.

**Coupling**

Perhaps even more significant a distinction of **composition** and **inheritance** is one along the lines of coupling; the degree of interdependence. Especially in the crucible of [the Single Responsibility principle](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2014/05/08/SingleReponsibilityPrinciple.html) one of the most foundational principle of good design.

Classes and objects created through inheritance are *tightly coupled* because they are designed around what they are thus behaviour is passed down from parent/super/base classes to children/sub classes hence classes and objects are derived from others (the IS-A relationship).

On the other hand, those created through composition are **loosely coupled** because they are designed around what they do thus are logically larger structures which contain others implementing desired behaviour that is much more contained and "isolated".

Coupling is a critical factor that determines maintenance complexity.

Between them, inheritance is much more misused perhaps because on the face of it, composition appears to be more complex; it really is not. The [Circle–ellipse problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle%E2%80%93ellipse_problem) explains the pitfalls of using (rather mis-using) subtype polymorphism (inheritance) in object modelling.

**Composition over Inheritance**

There's a principle of object oriented programming that classes should achieve polymorphic behavior and code reuse by their **composition** rather than **inheritance** from a base or parent class. This is the Composition over Inheritance or composite reuse principle.

Barbara Liskov's [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) is a rather handy litmus test in deciding whether to use composition or inheritance.

[Composition vs. Inheritance: How to Choose?](https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/composition-vs-inheritance-how-choose) is a great read on the subject.

Comment: thank you!! I read article https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/composition-vs-inheritance-how-choose . And having hard tome understanding "implementation class and domain class" . can you explain the two?

Comment: The difference between the two is merely a matter of belonging to a domain. 

If a class describes an entity belonging to a business domain it's a domain class. On the other hand, an implementation class would be a commonly used general purpose class without any domain.

An example of an implementation class given in the article is `ArrayList`. It does not describe business entities.

This contrasts with the `Customer` class that's mentioned. `Customer` would be a class that is part of the domain, where it is describing an entity specific to the business.

Comment: http://www.cs.sjsu.edu/~pearce/modules/lectures/ooa/analysis/IdentifyingDomainClasses.htm

Comment: thank you for your detail explanation!! I got the difference between domain and implementation class.